# Does a One to One Relationship make sense here?

Tags: python, database, django, python-3.x

OK, I'm working on a character sheet storage program from an RPG. Nothing too fancy right now, but it could get fancier. Here's the deal, I've attributes and skills which both have die codes (It's D6 for those who know the system). I've created a Die Code class which separates out dice and pips since the pips don't count for advancement costs. That also lets me create a roller function later if I want. I've also got an Attribute class.

So, I feel like a 1 to 1 relationship is what I should have here, right? Each Attribute or Skill has 1 and only 1 Die Code. But that Die Code is represented in program space as a separate object. Since usually 1 codespace object == 1 database table row, that means 2 tables with a 1:1 relationship. Am I completely off base or does this make sense? Are there any landmines I could be missing here?

Comment: Why the downvote? I've struggled with understanding database design in every program I've ever designed. I've searched online and I think I understand this particular case but I'm trying to clarify and stackoverflow is the best place I know for that. Is there a better format for me to ask this question that makes it not warrant a downvote? Does it belong in a different tag? Just trying to understand, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

OK, well I guess I'll answer my own question here. I've decided to use a 1:1 relationship here so that my database accurately models my code. Since the two will be the same, it should give me a clearer picture of exactly what happening inside my program, which is the whole goal anyway.